# issue in use python through chaquopy in android studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, chaquopy

Build file 'C:\Users\akash\AndroidStudioProjects\VIA\app\build.gradle' line: 3

An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.chaquo.python']

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.chaquo.python'.
> No such property: dslScope for class: com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.DefaultAndroidSourceDirectorySet

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: dslScope for class: com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.DefaultAndroidSourceDirectorySet
    at com.chaquo.python.PythonPlugin$_extendSourceSets_closure3.doCall(PythonPlugin.groovy:108)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:155)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:106)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.ConfigureUtil$WrappedConfigureAction.execute(ConfigureUtil.java:167)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$CurrentApplication$1.execute(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:123)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1.run(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:110)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction.execute(DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.all(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:159)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.all(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:194)
    at org.gradle.api.DomainObjectCollection$all.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.chaquo.python.PythonPlugin.extendSourceSets(PythonPlugin.groovy:103)
    at com.chaquo.python.PythonPlugin.apply(PythonPlugin.groovy:60)
    at com.chaquo.python.PythonPlugin.apply(PythonPlugin.groovy)
    ...
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using Gradle's new `pluginManagement` and `plugins` syntax, which is generated by the new project wizard in Android Studio Bumblebee. This requires Chaquopy 11.0.0 or later, so edit your app's top-level build.gradle file and change the version number of `com.chaquo.python`.

Or if you want to stay on an older version of Chaquopy, you can use the old `buildscript` syntax instead, as shown in [the documentation](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/10.0/android.html#android-plugin).

Comment: i get the same error. i changed the version number to 11.0.0 on my top-level build.gradle file but it doesnt work. what might be another solution?

Comment: Are you sure it's exactly the same error, including "No such property: dslScope"? If so, please edit your question to include your top-level build.gradle file, then post a comment below this answer to notify me. Or if the error is different, please ask a separate question.

Comment: Sorry, I've just noticed you're not the original questioner. So please do ask a separate question, including both the full error message and the content of your top-level build.gradle file.